# Having 'the response ended prematurely' exception on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

There is exception being occurred at client side saying **Error while copying the stream content** and below that **the response ended prematurely**.

I cant figure out the solution. In the server side I have asp.net core web api which modify response stream. It actually reads what the controller send and encrypts it to a string and then writes to the response stream.

Also when when the content type is `text/plain` the response is shown on the *Postman* but when the content-type is `application/json` the content is not shown but in the header I can see the content length having some numbers. And for client side, the above exception occurs for both the content-type.

So what i am missing in my middleware code??  I know this is causing issue because when i comment out `MyMiddleware` in startup.cs, the normal flow works.

Below is the `Invoke function` in middleware on the server side

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    string reponseContent = string.Empty;

    // Store the "pre-modified" response stream.
    var existingBody = context.Response.Body;

    using (var newBody = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // We set the response body to our stream so we can read after the chain of middlewares have been called.
        context.Response.Body = newBody;

        await next(context);

        // Set the stream back to the original.
        context.Response.Body = existingBody;

        newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //reading the content
        var contentReader = new StreamReader(newBody);
        reponseContent = await contentReader.ReadToEndAsync();

        string encryptedData = _cryptoService.Encrypt(reponseContent);

        // Send our modified content to the response body.
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(encryptedData);
}
```

Comment: Could you please try replacing this ` reponseContent = await contentReader.ReadToEndAsync();` line with this `reponseContent = await contentReader.ReadAsStringAsync();` let me know if anything change or error message changed.

Comment: Additionally share your this `_cryptoService` service details so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron the `contentReader` doesnt have `ReadAsStringAsync()` method. Also `_cryptoService.Encrypt()` takes string as input and encrypts the data with the public key of client and returns base64string. I think the problem is writing into response stream, maybe I am missing something while writing into response stream.

Comment: Hello would you kindly check the answer and double check your Middleware how are calling this on your `startus.cs` class. I think your may have implementational `glitch`

Answer (score 0):

I  am not sure how you are calling your MiddleWare. I have successfully reproduce the issue and get the response accordingly.

***`Middle Ware Class:`***

```
 public class CustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            string reponseContent = string.Empty;

            // Store the "pre-modified" response stream.
            var existingBody = context.Response.Body;

            using (var newBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // We set the response body to our stream so we can read after the chain of middlewares have been called.
                context.Response.Body = newBody;

                await next(context);

                // Set the stream back to the original.
                context.Response.Body = existingBody;

                newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //reading the content
                var contentReader = new StreamReader(newBody);
                reponseContent = await contentReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                //  string encryptedData = _cryptoService.Encrypt(reponseContent);

                // Send our modified content to the response body.
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(reponseContent);
            }

        }
    }
```

> ***`Note:`*** You should use constructor to invoke your `RequestDelegate`  like this way. But you have designed this with two parameter, not sure how you are passing the argument while calling.

***`Startup.cs:`***

Calling Middleware In `Startup.cs` under `Configure` like this way

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
```

***`Request From Postman:`***

I have tested with simple `plain text` and `application/json` type. Sent request to my controller and modify the argument on controller body, and the changed implemented on the middleware.

***`Controller:`***

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MiddlewareReStream([FromBody] Plans plan)
{
    plan.PlanName = "New Text";
    return Ok(plan);
}
```

***`MiddlWare Output:`***

[image]

***`Note:`*** Notice that I have invoke the request with `"PlanName":"Test Plan"` and modified the parameter which `middleware` successfully invoked the changes.

***`PostMan:`***
[image]

***`Note:`*** Make sure you have called or implemented the `InvokeAsync` Middleware accordingly. Because I got the response as you are expecting.

Comment: Problem still persist. When you uncomment the `encrypted` line.. the problem still exist. The `Encrypt()` is needed as it converts the response into encrpyted string. Problem is writing this encrypted form into stream. The encrypted data is plain string but from the controller it returned a model which is `application/json` . [See](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-108_2.png), this shows i am receiving the data but in the body there is nothing. I also tried serialising the string before writing into the stream, it didnt work

Comment: You haven't share `_cryptoService.Encrypt(reponseContent);`  implementation details, in that case you need to share it so that we can reproduce that problem

Comment: i have created a new repo for sharing. [See this](https://github.com/abhi-amr/RequestResponseMiddleware/tree/master/RequestResponseModification). It has middleware and the requirement is to decrypt the incoming request and encrypt the outgoing response. Comment if you need to know more. Have stuck in this problem for quite sometime.

Comment: So for my understanding problem on your service `_cryptoService.Encrypt(reponseContent);`. This is not acting as expected.

Comment: it encrypts and decrypts the data fine but using it causing the problem. Because whatever the content type would be whether `text/plain` or `application/json` the encrypt and decrypt function  returns string. If it is object then it would have written serialised string as when encrypting i would have serialize the object and then encrypted it. I dont know what should I do to fix the isssue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of `text/plain` or `application/json` do you usually receive? Does the type known?

Comment: Th client send data, it can be just a string or any model and the server receives it and pass on to the controller. The `MyMiddleware` will be on the client side and server side which will be decrypting incoming request and outgoing responses. And as you can infer from the repo, it encrypts the data whether it is string or model and returns encrypted string. As answer to your question, the type are not known before, the project have many models. Some controller returns model and some return string data, the usual asp.net core application.

Comment: My points was if we could build strongly type model and in case of need can pass it by `serialization` and `deserialization` if that could resove the issue. Other than your `encryption` and `dycrption` service I got no issue on the solution. Would you kindly try some other  `encryption` algorithm if the problem reslove.

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Comment: no, i need help with this only but appreciate your input. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share this `_cryptoService` detail implementaion so that we can assist on this.

Comment: I have already created a repo to share which includes also the `cryptoService` and i have share the link in the above comments. I will share it again, [Repo](https://github.com/abhi-amr/RequestResponseMiddleware/tree/master/RequestResponseModification)

Comment: Oh yes, I noticed, lets move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking that the "Content-Length" header of the response represents the size of the data before you encrypt it and that you need to recalculate the size based on the new encrypted data and reset the header. Im also thinking that different servers are reacting to this missmatch differently, That it might work on IIS but not Kestrel.

In short make sure your "Content-Length" and "Content-Type" headers are matching what you are actually sending.